# Limit width of CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

Is there a simple way of limiting the width of a CardView widget? On very large screens I want to keep space blank on either sides of the cards instead of stretching the card to make it extremely wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You should create alternative layout in *layouts-w600dp* dir, it will be used for big screens,
- **or** you can set

  ```
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/my_cardview_margin"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/my_cardview_margin"
  ```

  to your CardView

  and create *dimen.xml* in *values* dir and in *values-w600dp* dir with
  different value of *my_cardview_margin*

*...-w600dp* suffix means that it will be used when current screen width is greater or equal to 600 dp.